# XML Parser Package for Non-Valid String

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I have this kind of xml string which I got from DYMO printer API.

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Printers><LabelWriterPrinter><Name>DYMO LabelWriter 450<\/Name><ModelName>DYMO LabelWriter 450<\/ModelName><IsConnected>False<\/IsConnected><IsLocal>True<\/IsLocal><IsTwinTurbo>False<\/IsTwinTurbo><\/LabelWriterPrinter><\/Printers>\n"
```

As you can see, it includes quotes, escape () and new line (\n) characters inside it. I checked some XML to json packages but couldn't find an option to parse an XML in this format.
I can use manipulate the string with (substr, replace) methods but it doesn't look so clean. Do you know any package to handle this quickly? Also, I would like to learn what is the naming convention of this type of string template?

Comment: Escaped newlines is exactly how multi-line strings are represented, so I am not sure what you react to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a string containing perfectly valid XML. There's nothing special about it. I think you might be confused about the escaping, but that is how those symbols are represented in a string. Here's my REPL-ing in Node (observe how the string looks when printed - all escaped chars are gone):

```
const str='<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Printers><LabelWriterPrinter><Name>DYMO LabelWriter 450<\/Name><ModelName>DYMO LabelWriter 450<\/ModelName><IsConnected>False<\/IsConnected><IsLocal>True<\/IsLocal><IsTwinTurbo>False<\/IsTwinTurbo><\/LabelWriterPrinter><\/Printers>\n'
console.log(str)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Printers><LabelWriterPrinter><Name>DYMO LabelWriter 450</Name><ModelName>DYMO LabelWriter 450</ModelName><IsConnected>False</IsConnected><IsLocal>True</IsLocal><IsTwinTurbo>False</IsTwinTurbo></LabelWriterPrinter></Printers>

const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
parseString(str, function(err, res){ console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)) ; } )
{
  "Printers": {
    "LabelWriterPrinter": [
      {
        "Name": [
          "DYMO LabelWriter 450"
        ],
        "ModelName": [
          "DYMO LabelWriter 450"
        ],
        "IsConnected": [
          "False"
        ],
        "IsLocal": [
          "True"
        ],
        "IsTwinTurbo": [
          "False"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```